# C# Join with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I am using below query to join two tables and it works perfectly fine.

```
var joins = from filerow in dtfile.AsEnumerable()
            from dbrow in dtdb.AsEnumerable().Where(x =>
                filerow["PRODUCT_ID"] == x["PRODUCT_ID"]
                && filerow["COMPANY"] == x["COMPANY_NAME"]
                && filerow["BRAND"] == x["BRAND_ID"]
                && filerow["LOCATION"] == x["PLACE"]
              )
            select new { filerecord = filerow, db = dbrow };
```

I want to make column names as dynamic in dictionary and then use this dictionary to get join results.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictcolumnMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictcolumnMapping.Add("PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_ID");
dictcolumnMapping.Add("COMPANY", "COMPANY_NAME");
dictcolumnMapping.Add("BRAND", "BRAND_ID");
dictcolumnMapping.Add("LOCATION", "PLACE");
```

The reason is that , I want to implement this join for multiple tables and key columns are different for each table.

Comment: "multiple tables and key columns" please provide example for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this extension method. It allows you to add conditions dynamically by mapping dictionary.

```
public static IQueryable<DataRow> WhereByMapping(this IQueryable<DataRow> source, DataRow parentSource, Dictionary<string, string> dictcolumnMapping)
{
    foreach (var map in dictcolumnMapping)
    {
        source = source.Where(r => parentSource[map.Key] == r[map.Value]);
    }

    return source;
}
```

Then your query would be like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictcolumnMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictcolumnMapping.Add("PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_ID");
dictcolumnMapping.Add("COMPANY", "COMPANY_NAME");
dictcolumnMapping.Add("BRAND", "BRAND_ID");
dictcolumnMapping.Add("LOCATION", "PLACE");


var joins = from filerow in dtfile.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()
            from dbrow in dtdb.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().WhereByMapping(filerow, dictcolumnMapping)
            select new { filerecord = filerow, db = dbrow };
```

Comment: this is giving all rows from dtfile and not giving exactly mating rows.

Comment: Thank you so much , this is perfect

Comment: for my case I dont get any results at all :(

Comment: It is hard to say without knowing more detail @themhz. What is exactly not working?

Comment: I am using Dataset with Datatables and I am joining two datatables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73110450/join-tables-by-building-the-linq-query-in-run-time