# Join tables by building the LINQ query in run time

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do a dynamic query in LINQ. I want to to be able to construct the query after parsing a JSON object in run time. I looked at [dynamic linq](https://dynamic-linq.net/) and I managed to get the select part of the query working as well as the filtering "where" part. However I am having trouble to make a dynamic join to work.. meaning that I want to be able to join tables by building the LINQ query in run time.

I am trying to follow what was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197848/c-sharp-join-with-dynamic-columns/61205927#comment129071479_61205927) in order to make a dynamic join between two tables using LINQ. However I get no results when the query is being executed.

Tables are full of data and If I make a normal join I will get the results.

Here is my code

```
 DataTable Table1 = xml.DataSet.Tables["PageA"];
 DataTable Table2 = xml.DataSet.Tables["PageADetails"];

 Dictionary<string, string> dictcolumnMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();            
 dictcolumnMapping.Add("ID", "PageADetailID");


 var joins = from filerow in Table1.AsEnumerable()
             from dbrow in able2.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().WhereByMapping2(filerow, dictcolumnMapping)
             select new { filerecord = filerow, db = dbrow };
```

and the WhereByMapping2

```
public static class DynamicQueryableExtender
    {                
        public static IQueryable<DataRow> WhereByMapping2(this IQueryable<DataRow> source, DataRow parentSource, Dictionary<string, string> dictcolumnMapping)
        {
            foreach (var map in dictcolumnMapping)
            {
                source = source.Where(r => parentSource[map.Key] == r[map.Value]);
            }

            return source;
        }

    }
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Any way you can do a SQL trace on the database to see what the actual SQL is that is being used? I think there is probably a way to see this information in the debugger as well, but I usually just do a trace.

Comment: but its not in the Database it is simple a dataset that loads an xml

Comment: You did not provide what is the `WhereByMapping2`, but what do you see if you try this `var joins = from filerow in Table1.AsEnumerable()
             from dbrow in Table2.AsEnumerable().Where(x =>
                filerow["ID"] == x["PageADetailID"]
              )
             select new { filerecord = filerow, db = dbrow };`